# Pair Column A & B, get the matching results in C and the difference in D

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have columns "Manifesto A" and "Manifesto B" (with its correspondent volumes) that I get from my SQL Server 2008 DB. A has aprox. 1000 lines and B (and Volumes C) around 800, so it's almost impossible to compare they by hand.
Column "Manifesto C" must have the results of the A>B matching and pairing, and add blank cells where there is no match, as ***[this image example shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq9zM.jpg)***.

I've tried **[this](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/626378-pairing-up-data-in-two-columns.html)**, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333780/excel-pair-things-up-between-two-columns-a-and-b-and-show-unpaired-values-in)**, and some SQL ***CASE WHEN***. I don't know **VBA**, but I'll copy paste anything if you say so.

Can anyone help me sort this out?
Thx in advance! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you already have the data, you only need to pair it in *Excel*?
If so, suppose you have your data like below:

[image]

Use this formula in G3:
 `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,D$3:D$17,0))),B3,"")`

And this formula in H3:
 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G3,D$2:E$17,2,0),"")`

Copy it to the rest of the cells.
For some reason, I don't know why your image didn't show up the result for `32490` and `32563` which are both present in **Manifesto A** and **B**. HTH.

Comment: Hey. So, everything worked fine until I got doubled "Manifesto" numbers for different users.
[Here is a example](http://imgur.com/1DMY2wP) of what is happening.
The positioning of the "Manifesto" column under "Results C" is OK, but the "Volumes" are wrong. They are copying the volumes only from the first repeated Manifesto 17616, that belongs to user '30'. The other users have the same Manifesto number, but with different Volumes.

I didn't foresaw this replication... Is it possible to check by the  Manifesto AND by the User?

Tks again!

Comment: @Human_AfterAll Ah that should have been another question don't you think? It is not included in the original question in the first place. This answer will stay as is since it answers your original question. But that is doable but using a different formula.

Comment: ok, man. Sorry about it... I'm totally noob here. Will post and explain it again! Thk