# Pair columns A and B, get the matching data in C considering doubled values for different users

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have columns ***"Manifestos A"*** and ***"Manifestos B"*** (with its correspondent *"volumes"*). ***"A"*** has more than 1000 lines and ***"B"*** around 800, so its impossible doing by hand.

Column ***"Manifestos C"*** must have the results of ***"A"*** > ***"B"*** matching and pairing, and add blank cells where there is no match .

This was done before **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812772/pair-column-a-b-get-the-matching-results-in-c-and-the-difference-in-d)** and was all OK until I found out that some cells might have the same values in columns ***"A"*** and ***"B"***. I did not foresaw this.

I've made an example to show what happened when I applied the [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812941/4229024) I got to my other question:

[image: worksheet showing 3 tables with 3 column each (User, Manifesto and Volumes), with duplicate Manifesto values highlighted in all tables and duplicate volumes for same manifestos in column "Volumes C", showing the error]

Note that the pairing is perfectly fine, but the ***"Volumes C"*** cells are being repeated from the volumes coupled up with the first **"17616"** manifesto cell on column ***"Manifestos B"***, and this cannot happen.

The formula for cell *K3* and bellow:

`=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(C3,G$3:G$15,0))),C3,"")`

And for cell *L3* and bellow

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K3,G$3:H$15,2,0),"")`

---

Now I have to add the "User" filter to the equation so I can get the expected results below:

[image: worksheet showing 3 tables with 3 column each (User, Manifesto and Volumes), with duplicate Manifesto values highlighted in all tables and distinct volumes for same manifestos in column "Volumes C", showing the expected result]

Comment: It's not very clear which column your formulas are supposed to be in.

Comment: idk where the formulas should actually be as I don't know much Excel. question reformulated to be more object. will explain it better if needed. tks

Comment: well done! all that's missing is the actual exact formula you're using in column `L` [Volumes C], that's returning the wrong result ;)

Comment: added the previously used formulas! tks for being noob friendly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try this formula in "L3" and copy it down:

```
=SUMIFS($H$3:$H$15;$F$3:$F$15;J3;$G$3:$G$15;K3)
```

Comment: Excel has returned that I've "entered an excessive number of arguments for this function".tks

Comment: @Human_AfterAll this should work. Replace `;` with `,` though.

Comment: The `SUMIFS` should be the *value_if_false* in an `IF` function to make an empty value when `$K3` is an empty string: `=IF($K3="","",SUMIFS(...))`

Comment: @retailcoder my bad, was translating it as `SUMIF`. had to increase all by 1, but it worked like a charm!!!

the final formula on "L3" is `=SUMIFS($H$4:$H$16;$F$4:$F$16;J4;$G$4:$G$16;K4)`.
thank you very much!

will give it some further testing tomorrow and will get back if any errors!

Comment: thanks @retailcoder! Continental European OS, forgot to change the syntax....and was a bit lazy with the blank values...